# Alternatives for Suggested Routes

Tags: macos, maps

Apple maps shows "1 of 3 Suggested Routes".

How do I get to see the alternatives?

Comment: Does not the alternate routes show in a lighter color and touching the alternate shift the darker color to it while the previous focused route is now lighter?

Comment: @user3439894 add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Apple Maps shows alternate routes they'll appear in a lighter color then the primary route and touching the alternate route shift the darker color to it, changing the route details, while the previous focused route is now the lighter one.